# could not find function "ceil" error, when trying to plot histogram

Tags: r

U Aight guys. I am very new to Rstudio only knew about it this week. I am using windows 8 and R studio the newest version and have installed RGui as well.
I am trying to plot a histogram for some data and keep getting this error message, even when I try the code in RGui:

> screen(1)
>   histplot(t(X),"metabolites: Hist")
>   Error in histplot(t(X), "metabolites: Hist") : 
>     could not find function "ceil"

Why does it ask me for "ceil" what does this mean? I just want to plot my histogram?
My data is represented in 4 rows by 200 columns and in the first column is 4 different names of variables. I.e. each row represents data from a different variable.

I am thinking its because I would need to do a histogram for each row separately rather than trying to do a histogram for all data. Could this be the reason the error is coming up?

I am using the package histplot.r, here is the script for histplot:

```
histplot <- function(x,sam) {
nn <- ceil(sqrt(length(x)))
BW <- (max(x)-min(x))/nn
xxx <- hist(x, freq = TRUE, main=sam)
N <- xxx$counts # Get the freq distribution
MIDS <- xxx$mids # Get the centres
Xaxis <- seq(min(x), max(x), by = 0.01)
MU <- mean(x)
SIGMA <- std(x)
y <- exp(-0.5 * ((Xaxis - MU)/SIGMA)^2) / (sqrt(2*pi) * SIGMA)
matplot(Xaxis, (y * BW * sum(N)), type="l", col = 2, lty = 1, lwd = 1, add = TRUE)
abline(a=NULL,b=NULL, h=NULL, v=MU, col=3, lty=2, lwd=1) #  Add mean
abline(a=NULL,b=NULL, h=NULL, v=MU-SIGMA, col=4, lty=2, lwd=1) # Add mean-stdev
abline(a=NULL,b=NULL, h=NULL, v=MU+SIGMA, col=4, lty=2, lwd=1) # Add mean+stdev
}
```

The histplot didn't work when I run it in my script in Rstudio, screen 1. Here is my full script:

```
rm(list=ls())
graphics.off()
source("histplot.r")
source("normplot.r")
X <- read.table("metabolites.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE)

x11()
split.screen(c(1,2))
screen(1)
histplot (t(X), "Metabolites: Hist")
screen(2)
bbb <- qqplot(t(X), ppoints(t(X)), ylab =
                  "Probability", main = "metabolites: Norm")
qqplot(bbb)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the packages you're using since `histplot` is not in base `R`.  Also, if you include a reproducible data set, you'll wind up getting much better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ceil` function is a function that `histplot` uses under the hood. It is not part of a standard R install, and not part of any of the additional packages you loaded. This leads to the error you get, it cannot find the `ceil` function. I suspect the `ceil` function has the same functionality as the `ceiling` function, but I'm just speculating here.

Probably the `ceil` function is part of a package on which the `histplot` package depends. Try reinstalling the package with `dependencies = TRUE`. From your comment it turned out you needed to also load the `matlab` package, which contains the `ceil` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I dont know where depedancies is! All I did was download the histplot package from a folder we are using to do this work. Would I need to redownload histplot from a website instead whereby I can do the dependencies= TRUE bit?

Comment: Installing packages is generally done using the `install.packages` function, which has a `dependencies` argument. See `?install.packages` (the documentation of that function) for more details.

Comment: Just tried the install packages and still got the ceil error! here is my script.


install.packages("histplot.r", dependencies=TRUE)

Message that came up is:
histplot (t(X), "Metabolites: Hist")
Error in histplot(t(X), "Metabolites: Hist") : 
  could not find function "ceil"

Comment: No worries now. I have been advised that I indeed need to use require (matlab) to do this so that I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ceil function is in the pracma library

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/ceil